# How do I remove that container from a pod?

Tags: podman

Currently whenever I try to add a container to a pod, I get an error,

> Error: error creating container storage: the container name "database" is already in use by [SHA1]]. **You have to remove that container to be able to reuse that name.: that name is already in use**

How do I remove that container from a pod? I don't see a command under `podman pod` that will do it? I also don't see the container under `podman container ls -a`

```bsh
podman pod rm foo
podman pod create --name foo
podman run --pod foo --name cfoo --detach alpine:3 /bin/sh -c -- "echo sleeping for 100; sleep 100"
podman run --pod foo --name cbar --detach alpine:3 /bin/sh -c -- "echo sleeping for 100; sleep 100"
podman run --pod foo --name cbaz --detach alpine:3 /bin/sh -c -- "echo sleeping for 100; sleep 100"
```

Comment: remove a container with `podman rm [containerName/Id]`. if you do `podman ps -aq --filter id=CONTAINER_ID` is that there?